# Magento get category ID but from outside theme files (extension)

Tags: php, magento, categories, product

I have been having troubles for hours with this and it seems like it should be so simple.

I am making my first extension and want if a product is part of a category it does something. Its working fine in view.phtml but when I try and load it from my extension it doesnt work.

Originally I have been using:

```html
<?php $yourCatIds = array(1,3);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();
```

But I know $_product wont work inside the extension and that I need to get the Model. I have tried:

```html
<?php $yourCatIds = array(1,3,5,6);
   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
   $productCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);



 if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {}
      else {
      }
    ?>
```

And:

```html
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id']);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

And a few others I have seen on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working. I dont get an error just dont get the same as when I do it in the phtml files.

Can anyone tell me where I am being silly?

**UPDATE: THIS IS AS FAR AS I CAN GET BUT IT IS NOT WORKING**
It prints "not working" :(

```html
<?php
 
class Battery_Function_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
 
 public function test(){
 
 $yourCatIds = array(1,2,3,5,6,24);
 $productCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
      if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
           echo '<a href="#" style="float:right" title="You can only take 1x 160Wh battery or 2x batteries under 100Wh, in your handluggage ONLY." class="masterTooltip">Traveling on a Plane <img style="display: inline-block" src="http://www.somerset.lib.nj.us/images/help.gif"></a><br>';
      }
      else {
      print("not working ");
      } 
 

 }
 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the data step by step:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$productCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
```

You can use `dump($productCats)`, see is there some data. If is `NULL`, you should check the code. If there are some data ,then go the next step, show the data just like `$productCats`.

Comment: I changed $cat_id as i noticed pasted this in wrong. I have used dump($productCats) and I get lots of information but nothing points to the category ID. I have also dumpped $category which gives me a string (1) - 2 but I have checked and the category is 3 not 2 so Im lost. The var dump is too large to paste here so not sure what to do :/